# Are object tags set by the JVM visible to JVMTI agents?

Tags: tags, jvmti

JVMTI agents often need to traverse the Java heap and visit each live object precisely once. One technique is to call [FollowReferences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#FollowReferences) and avoid traversing a given object more than once by:

- Tagging each object visited using [SetTag](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#SetTag), and
- Filtering out tagged objects, e.g. by setting `JVMTI_HEAP_FILTER_TAGGED` in the Heap Filter Flags.

There is, however, a problem in picking a suitable tag value. The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#Heap) for object tags states:

> Tags are local to the environment; that is, the tags of one environment are not visible in another.

Since each JVMTI agent has its own environment, this protects one agent from clashing with tags set by another agent. However, the documentation doesn't appear to state whether tags set by the JVM itself, e.g. during garbage collection, are visible in a JVMTI environment. Are they visible or not?

If tags set by the JVM itself *are* visible, the agent needs to avoid clashing with any such tags, e.g. by clearing all the tags first or by somehow picking a tag that is not already in use.

Comment: You may care to explain why the [Heap iteration functions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#Heap_1_0) are not suitable. Do some of these visit each object only once?

Comment: Those are no better actually and I didn't want to distract from the main question. Essentially there are two sets of functions. Those which follow references, and therefore can be used to find just the live objects, all have similar behaviour to `FollowReferences` and face the tagging issue. The others find live and dead objects, which wasn't what we wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the Hotspot code in [jvmtiTagMap.cpp](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-hotspot/blob/master/src/share/vm/prims/jvmtiTagMap.cpp) and observing that the corresponding [header file](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-hotspot/blob/master/src/share/vm/prims/jvmtiTagMap.hpp) is only included in JVMTI code, it seems very likely that the garbage collector does not use a tag map for its own tagging.

So the answer to the question is almost certainly that tags set by the JVM itself are *not* visible in a JVMTI environment.